# Php looping through an array to select from database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach

I have a list of numbers that I exploded into an array. I then want to loop through the array and use the value from the array to call information out of a database. I tried to use the `mysqli_data_seek` to reset the result but the second loop throws an error.

```
<?php 
$relatedArt = explode(",",$art["art_related"]); 

foreach($relatedArt as $value) { 

$relatedQ = "SELECT art_id,art_name,art_thumb FROM zoo_art WHERE art_id = ".$value." "; 

$relatedR = mysqli_query($connection, $relatedQ); 

confirm_query($relatedR, "problem"); 

mysqli_data_seek($relatedR, 0);                             
} 
?>
```

Comment: Instead of querying for each item in the array, look up what MySQL's `IN` operator does. Don't use mysql_* functions since they're outdated, use PDO. Entire code you posted can be shrunk into two lines of code using two things I mentioned so take a few minutes to get familiar with them.

Comment: @N.B OP is using mysqli, not mysql

Comment: I apologize, my mistake, good catch.

Comment: @Daryl, am sorry because am new here, what does `OP` refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this insted of foreach loop.

```
$relatedArt = explode($art["art_related"]);
$values = implode(",",$relatedArt); 
$relatedQ = "SELECT art_id,art_name,art_thumb FROM zoo_art WHERE art_id IN(".$values.") ";
```

IN Operetor is used to to query database in any given order.

Comment: `$relatedArt` would be an array in your example

Comment: yes. It is an exploded list of numbers that came from a database call.

Comment: @kayann then you can just do implode.